# Unable to access network with ethernet connection

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, routing, proxmox

I'm running into issues trying to connect to my network from a new machine running Proxmox (Debian Buster) with a [5.11 kernel](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/kernel-5-11.86225/). This kernel was necessary to support the Intel I219V Ethernet connection on my motherboard. Below is the configuration of the network, and logs of it failing when attempting to ping both the router and 8.8.8.8.

```bsh
root@pve:~# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master vmbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:a1:59:6a:fe:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: vmbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d2:32:44:29:bc:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.42.43/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global vmbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d032:44ff:fe29:bc63/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@pve:~# dhcp enp0s31f6

root@pve:~# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master vmbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:a1:59:6a:fe:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.10/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic enp0s31f6
       valid_lft 85711sec preferred_lft 85711sec
    inet6 fe80::aaa1:59ff:fe6a:fe3e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: vmbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d2:32:44:29:bc:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.42.43/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global vmbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d032:44ff:fe29:bc63/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@pve:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp0s31f6 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.42.43/24
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        bridge_ports enp0s31f6
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

root@pve:~# ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev vmbr0 onlink
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.10
192.168.42.0/24 dev vmbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.43

root@pve:~# ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.10 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.10 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.10 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.10 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

root@pve:~# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
# hangs here indefinitely...
```

Comment: I only skimmed the question at this time, and noted a few immediate concerns. Check with your local network technician about the values you are using. For one thing, when you `ping 192.168.0.1`, the host at 192.168.0.10 is replying, saying it cannot reach host 192.168.0.1. That sounds like the gateway should be 192.168.0.10. For the `ping 8.8.8.8`, it may be failing  a DNS resolve. Try `ping -n -c 4 8.8.8.8` instead. The '-n' means "do not try to DNS resolve". ('-c 4' means try four pings, which is usually the default anyhow for non-root.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interface vmbr0 is configured with a default gateway in a different subnet (in other words another logical range) than the IP address. The gateway IP tells the system how to get to another subnet, and without it, packets won't leave the current subnet.

For instance, the 192.168.42.0/24 subnet has the following range of usable IP addresses:

```
192.168.42.1 - 192.168.42.254
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This was it. You have solved the issue that has been troubling me for more hours than I'd like to admit!